# Ошибка в переборном алгоритме python

Tags: python

Задание.
В массив с клавиатуры вводится N (N <= 100) положительных целых чисел, не превышающих 1000.
Требуется определить максимальное произведение двух элементов массива, кратное 3 и оканчивающееся
на 1. На вход программе в первой строке подается количество чисел N, а затем N положительных целых
чисел. Программа должна вывести одно число – максимальное произведение двух чисел, кратное 3 и
оканчивающееся на 1

```
n = int(input())

a = []
max_pr = 0

for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(input()))
    
for i in range(n-1):
    if (a[i] % 3  != 0) and (a[i] % 10 != 1):
        continue
    for j in range(1, n):
        if a[i] == a[j]:
            continue
        if a[j] % 3  == 0 and a[j] % 10 == 1 and (a[i] * a[j]) > max_pr:
            max_pr = a[i] * a[j]
print(max_pr)
```

Если в массиве числа к примеру 90, 81, 21, 44 то выводит 7290, если 21, 44, 81, 90 то выводит правильный ответ 1701

Comment: произведение двух чисел, кратное 3 и оканчивающееся на 1.  . .проверка кратности и окончания у вас идёт до умножения, но по идее должна идти после.

Answer (score 1):

"Требуется определить максимальное произведение двух элементов массива, кратное 3 и оканчивающееся на 1."
Тут говорится о том что максимальное произведение должно быть кратное 3 и оканчиваться на 1.

```
n = int(input())

a = []
max_pr = 0

for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(input()))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 1, n)
        c_pr = a[i] * a[j]
        if (c_pr % 3 == 0) and (c_pr % 10 == 1) and c_pr > max_pr:
            max_pr = c_pr
print(max_pr)
```

Comment: `range(n - 1)` это не правильно надо `range(n)`

Comment: Невнимательно прочитал. Я делал находил максимальное произведение из чисел кратных 3 и оканчивающихся на 1. Но почему-то всё равно не вышло(

Comment: @Danis Да, верно, исправил

Comment: Вложенный цикл `for j in range(i+1, n):` будет получше